# attaching a Client control ID and value to the Request object...possible?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a Grid view in which the columns are Databound Item templates. 
I need to attach the client Id of a control(Hyperlink) and its value to the request object while posting it back to the server(since Viewstate is turned off). 
Using the Client Id, I can write code to retrieve the value of the hyperlink 'text' field.

Is this possible in any way? Or, can you guys suggest me an alternative approach to doing this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Have some JavaScript save the control's ID into a hidden input field in the form. You can then read the posted form field from the Request object on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ItemDataBound event of the GridView, then do a findcontrol for the hyperlink and set the navigationurl to the correctly formatted link

It is not nice, but it works.

```
private void gridClientAccounts_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
        DataRowView myRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        var unlockButton = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("nameId");


        string url = string.Format("~/folder/page.aspx?id={0}&param2={1}", myRow["clientId"], unlockButton.ClientID);

        unlockButton.NavigateUrl = url ;
     }
  }
```

with hyperlink:
   <asp:TemplateColumn>
                  <HeaderTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lbheader" runat="server">headertext</asp:Label>
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:HyperLink ID="nameId" runat="server" CssClass="link" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.NAME") %>'>
                     </asp:HyperLink> 
                  </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateColumn>